# Using SELECT'd Case Statement's columnName in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my query:

```
SELECT d.DeptName, CASE WHEN e.WorkCity is NULL THEN 'Mobile'
                                           ELSE 'Stationary'
                        END AS EmpType,
        AVG(e.MonthlyPayScale) AS AvgMnthPay
FROM Department d, Employee e
WHERE d.DeptId = e.DeptId
GROUP BY d.DeptName, EmpType
ORDER BY d.DeptName, EmpType
```

This is my output which seems to be right:

```
 deptname |  emptype   |       avgmnthpay
----------+------------+------------------------
 EvanDept | Mobile     |  7500.0000000000000000
 MaxDept  | Stationary | 11250.0000000000000000
 PaulDept | Mobile     |  5000.0000000000000000
 PaulDept | Stationary | 12500.0000000000000000
(4 rows)
```

It groups by department name and mobile/stationary employees, and calculates the average monthly pay of the employees of each group.

From what I understand though, this is the ordering of SQL queries:

```
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
SELECT
ORDER BY
```

So the GROUP BY statement happens **before** the SELECT statement. So why does:

GROUP BY d.DeptName, **EmpType**

Know anything about EmpType, which is declare in the CASE statement inside the SELECT statement?

So basically, **why** does my code work when GROUP BY is evaluated before SELECT?

Comment: My SQL [Extends the `GROUP BY` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) in a number of ways, this is one of them (at the bottom of the page linked). I don't know about the inner workings  of MySQL query compilation, so while the order of operations you have stated is correct, (Although missing `HAVING`), I can't explain exactly why the extension works.

Comment: Tag dbms used. MySQL and Postgresql are very different when it comes to GROUP BY.

Comment: A general tip (dbms independent): `GROUP BY d.DeptName, e.WorkCity`.

Comment: My bad... I'm using Postgresql. I thought I should be grouping by EmpType because I want to calculate the average for different DeptNames and EmpTypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processing that you describe is often used to explain the *compilation* of a query and what identifiers are known when.  SQL Server is very explicit about this, and their rules are documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx).

Just because SQL Server does it that way, does not mean that all databases do it that way.

So, different databases are better or worse at allowing column aliases in the various clauses.  MySQL and Postgres allow column aliases in the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses; Oracle and SQL Server do not.  All databases allow column aliases in the `ORDER BY`.  In fact some, such as Hive, require a column alias and don't allow aggregation functions.

I'm sure that the ANSI standard has something to say on this topic.  Whether it is actually unambiguous is another question, but different databases have different personalities.

And, this discussion refers to the *lexical* analysis of the query.  The actual execution order has nothing to do with the original statements.  Most databases engines use a dataflow engine and there is not a one-to-one correspondence between the dataflow operators and the SQL constructs.

Answer (score 1):

Do the `CASE` expression in a derived table:

```
select DeptName, EmpType, AVG(MonthlyPayScale) AS AvgMnthPay
FROM
(
  SELECT d.DeptName as DeptName,
         CASE WHEN e.WorkCity is NULL THEN 'Mobile'
              ELSE 'Stationary'
         END AS EmpType,
         e.MonthlyPayScale as MonthlyPayScale
  FROM Department d
      JOIN Employee e ON d.DeptId = e.DeptId
)
GROUP BY DeptName, EmpType
ORDER BY DeptName, EmpType
```

Did also switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and also easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: My question was more along the lines of **why** does my code work when GROUP BY is evaluated before SELECT?

Comment: According to the ANSI SQL standard, your query shouldn't work. I guess the Postgresql developers had too many people asking for this somewhat odd extension - adjusting to a very common beginner's programming error... (Several other dbms products also have this extension.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the name resolution in Postgresql allows this.

From the documentation for Postgresql 9.3 (*section 7.2.3. The GROUP BY and HAVING Clauses*):

> In strict SQL, GROUP BY can only group by columns of the source table
>   but PostgreSQL extends this to also allow GROUP BY to group by columns
>   in the select list. Grouping by value expressions instead of simple
>   column names is also allowed.

[Link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html)